# Scaling an image is slow on an iPad 4th gen, are there faster alternatives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, scaling, image-scaling

I'm trying to zoom and translate an image on the screen.

here's my drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, senderScale, senderScale);
    [self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(imgposx, imgposy)];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

When `senderScale` is 1.0, moving the image (`imgposx/imgposy`) is very smooth. But if senderScale has any other value, performance takes a big hit and the image stutters when I move it.

The image I am drawing is a `UIImage`object. I create it with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
```

and draw a simple `UIBezierPath(stroke)`:

```
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Turning off the anti-aliasing did not improve things much.

Edit:
I tried this:

```
rectImage = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width * senderScale, self.frame.size.height * senderScale);
[image drawInRect:rectImage];
```

but it was just as slow as the other method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to perform well, you should let the GPU do the heavy lifting by using CoreAnimation instead of drawing the image in your `-drawRect:` method. Try creating a view and doing:

```
myView.layer.contents = self.image.CGImage;
```

Then zoom and translate it by manipulating the UIView relative to its superview.  If you draw the image in `-drawRect:` you're making it do the hard work of blitting the image for every frame.  Doing it via CoreAnimation only blits once, and then subsequently lets the GPU zoom and translate the layer.

Comment: I tried creating a view but I couldn't figure out where I should put the translate and scaling code.

Comment: For translation you can just set the `frame` origin. For more complex transforms use the `transform` property.